# Wrong user data in database

Tags: php

With this script, I want to change the user data via the admin panel.

But when I want to change the details of the order, there is the figure '1' in the database are not the actual data.

Now my question is, what am I doing wrong with the following script?

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
$gebruikersnaam = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$motto = htmlspecialchars($_POST['motto']);
$rank = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rank']);
$locatie = htmlspecialchars($_POST['locatie']);
$geslacht = htmlspecialchars($_POST['geslacht']);
$biografie = htmlspecialchars($_POST['biografie']);
$rank = htmlspecialchars($_POST['muntjes']);
$profiel_gastenboek = htmlspecialchars($_POST['profiel_gastenboek']);

if (empty($gebruikersnaam) || empty($email) || empty($motto) ||
    empty($locatie) || empty($geslacht) || empty($biografie) || empty($rank)) {
    echo '<div class="callout callout-danger">
            <h4>Niet alle velden ingevuld!</h4>
            <p>Je hebt niet alle velden ingevuld.</p>
          </div>';
} 

$sql = "UPDATE gebruikers SET gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam', email='$email',
        motto='$motto', rank='$rank', locatie='$locatie', geslacht='$geslacht',
        biografie='$biografie', muntjes='$muntjes',
        profiel_gastenboek='$profiel_gastenboek' WHERE id='".$id."'";

/* Als alles is goedgekeurd, worden de gegevens in de database ingevoerd.  */
mysqli_query($con, $sql)
          or die ('Kon de gebruiker niet aanpassen: ' . mysqli_error($con));

      echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ' .
           'url=gebruikers-bewerken?melding=succesvol" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Your query execution part should be in the `else` part of your validation, otherwise the query will always be executed nonetheless.

Comment: Reformatted code block, removed excessive whitespace and indentation

Answer (score -2):

I believe that your update values need to break into strings like your `WHERE` clause. It should look like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE gebruikers SET gebruikersnaam = '" . $gebruikersnaam . "', email='" . $email . "', ..."
```

and so on.

Comment: Variables enclosed in double [quotes](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) will be expanded in PHP, meaning they will be substituted with their responding value

Answer (score -2):

Try this out:

```
$sql = "UPDATE gebruikers 
        SET gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam', 
        email='$email', 
        motto='$motto', 
        rank='$rank', 
        locatie='$locatie', 
        geslacht='$geslacht', 
        biografie='$biografie', 
        muntjes='$muntjes', 
        profiel_gastenboek='$profiel_gastenboek' 
        WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: This won't make any difference as the result output is the same